# Accessing Microsoft SQL Server from Tcl running on GNU/Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, connection-string, tcl

I'm looking for a source to explain how to use connection-strings, as a client from Linux. I am working with **tcl** in Linux environment and get a connection-string that supposed to connect me to a Microsoft SQL server.

Do you know of a good source that shoes how to connect to a server with a connection string, and how to connect from Linux?

All the sources I found online talk about creating server strings, and don't address Linux usage at all.

Comment: For which interface/programming language?

Comment: @Mat, to the best of my knowledge it's a custom made system written in visual basic using SQL, working on a Microsoft OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question *per se* has no sense: "connection strings" is the concept which is not inherent to programming languages or database servers.  Connection strings pertain to database *connection libraries* and usually they even differ between different *database drivers* used by those libraries.

Now back to the point. Personally, I'm using [tclodbc](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tclodbc) with the [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) driver.  How to build connection strings for the FreeTDS ODBC driver, is explained [here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm).

I do not use connection strings directly; instead I use "ODBC sources" which are configured system-wide, in the `/etc/odbc.ini` file (managed by the `unixodbc` as packaged in Debian). Basically, that file contains entries like this:

```
[SERVER1]
Description = MS SQL Server on server1.domain.local
Driver      = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Servername  = SERVER1
```

and the `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` file contains matching entries like this:

```
[SERVER1]
    host = server1.domain.local
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
    client charset = UTF-8
```

Now, in my Tcl code I have something like this:

```
set source SERVER1
database connect dbconn $source $user $password
...
```

Comment: Note that from Tcl 8.6 onwards you might have better results with [tdbc](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tdbc) which is now *the standard* Tcl database connectivity level.

Comment: There's a tdbc::odbc driver under development.

Comment: @kostix, could you please put a full example. Including all the code required for a successful connection.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed, with system-wide ODBC DSNs and entries for the servers configured in the FreeTDS configuration file, that `database connect` command is really the *only* thing which is needed to connect, so there's no "full code" which I hid from you. But [it seems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10829621/720999) you're battling with DSN-less setup, so I'll try to investigate your case in that discussion.