# How to define a driver for tclodbc?

Tags: sql, odbc, tcl, freetds

I want to use tclodbc from Linux environment to connect to a MS SQL server. I have the driver (freeTDS) and the connection string. But I don't know how to configure the driver to be used by tclodbs. There is a command

> **database configure** *operation driver attributes*

But I don't know what to put as `operation` and `attributes`, and whether this is the right command.

Related to my question: [Accessing Microsoft SQL Server from Tcl running on GNU/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634158/accessing-microsoft-sql-server-from-tcl-running-on-gnu-linux/10635949#10635949)

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's my take based on [these](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm) [guides](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/dsnless.htm) about how to make a DSN-less connection using the FreeTDS driver.

I've tested it a Debian Lenny system having `tclodbc` 2.5-5, `unixodbc` 2.2.11 and `libdbd-freetds` 0.8.2-1-4.1 and `tcl` 8.4.16-2 installed against an instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

```
package require tclodbc

proc cs_append {varName args} {
    set alen [llength $args]
    if {$alen < 2 || $alen % 2 != 0} {
        return -code error "Wrong # args: should be varName key value ?key value?"
    }

    upvar 1 $varName qs

    foreach {key value} $args {
        if {$qs ne ""} {
            append qs \;
        }
        append qs $key = \{ [string map {\{ \\\{} $value] \}
    }
}

set user test
set pass secret

set cs ""
cs_append cs DRIVER FreeTDS UID $user PWD $pass \
    Server myserver.domain.local \
    ClientCharset UTF-8 \
    APP "My test app"

database connect db $cs
foreach row [db {select * from MyDatabase..MyTable}] {
    puts $row
}
db disconnect
```

Some notes:

- The FreeTDS driver must be known to the ODBC subsystem by means of it being registeded in the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file.  I suppose that at least on my system appropriate packages take care of this by themselves but you'd better verify if you have FreeTDS registered in that file, otherwise that `DRIVER=FreeTDS` bit in the connection string won't work as ODBC will have no idea how to load the named driver library.
- The `ClientCharset` and `APP` connection string parameters *do not work in my case.* While I can live with the second, the first one sucks big time because in this case the character data is returned in some botched encoding.

  But there's no such problem when I use named server from the `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` file using the `ServerName=THAT_SERVER` instead of `Server=SERVER_HOST` in the connection string.  Unfortunately, this kind of defeats half of the purpose of using DSN-less setup.

  Quite possibly it's a bug in my version of the FreeTDS driver, and I have a really outdated system here, so YMMV and you better check yourself on your system.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the [documentation](http://tclodbc.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tclodbc/tclodbc/doc/reference.htm?revision=1.5), we see that there are 6 operations, of which the one you probably want is `add_dsn`. An example is included (below, with a small correction):

```
set driver "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)" 
set attributes [list "DSN=mydsn" "DBQ=c:\mydb.mdb" "FIL=MS Access"] 
database configure add_dsn $driver $attributes
```

I'm afraid you'll have to consult the FreeTDS documentation to get the right collection of attributes, but I *think* (based on [this evidence](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/dsnless.htm)) that you'll have the driver being `FreeTDS` and the attributes *might* be OK if it is an empty list (or with just `TDS_Version=5.0` in it). I really don't know too much about configuring ODBC…

Comment: I'm afraid that `database configure add_dsn ...` command would attempt to configure a per-user DSN (probably creating/updating some well-known file under the user's home directory) which is probably not what's intended.  Seems like the OP took somewhat wrong route--the proper one is to go for DSN-less setup.